# Mouse settings won't change primary button - 16.04 LTS

Tags: system-settings

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I cannot change the default primary button of mouse. It is recognized but I cannot save changes.

Comment: Not so good at this topic, and it seems people aren't answering. But maybe it is because you don't have enough permissions? Make sure your account is an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Also I have big problems with the mouse since I installed 16.04

It is like in universal access things were switched on:

In any case you should control y
 Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.
Open Universal Access and select the Pointing and Clicking tab